# MockMVC multipart returns 404 with context-path

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using MockMvc multipart in spring boot to test a RestController which accepts a multipart file.

The test runs fine when I don't set context-path in application.yml but as soon as I set it to something the mockMvc returns 404.

Following config works:

Application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8080
  servlet:
    context-path: /
  use-forward-headers: true
  forward-headers-strategy: FRAMEWORK
```

Test.java

```
// setup
        String templateUploadUrl = "http://localhost:8080/v1/file/upload?name=%s";

        byte[] templateContent = DataFactory.getFileAsByteArray();
        String contentParameterName = "file";
        String fileName = "fileName";

        MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile(contentParameterName, templateContent);

        templateUploadUrl = String.format(templateUploadUrl, fileName);
        this.mvc.perform(multipart(templateUploadUrl).file(multipartFile));
```

But following config gives 404:

Application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8080
  servlet:
    context-path: /context
  use-forward-headers: true
  forward-headers-strategy: FRAMEWORK
```

Test.java

```
// setup
        String templateUploadUrl = "http://localhost:8080/context/v1/file/upload?name=%s";

        byte[] templateContent = DataFactory.getFileAsByteArray();
        String contentParameterName = "file";
        String fileName = "fileName";

        MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile(contentParameterName, templateContent);

        templateUploadUrl = String.format(templateUploadUrl, fileName);
        this.mvc.perform(multipart(templateUploadUrl).file(multipartFile));
```

Comment: You just wanted to let us know?:) According to your tags you are using Spring Boot. Spring Boot doesn't have a context unless you explicitly set it, which I don't think you did.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was not aware. I am actually using spring-boot but it might not be relevant in this context

Comment: while keeping the context-path, what happens if your test makes a call to the endpoint without `/context`?
Moreover, show us the logs of the app starting before the tests start

Comment: Keeping the context-path and calling to the endpoint without ```/context```,  then this particular test passes. But my other tests fail which uses RestTemplate. What exactly would you want from the logs? The logs are pretty large in my Test Suite :(

Comment: For now, I have switched MockMvc to the RestTemplate for this test case and it is working fine with the context-path. But I am not sure why MockMvc is failing.

Comment: What annotation did you use for your test ? You need to use annotations WebMvcTest or SpringBootTest  + AutoConfigureMockMvc.

Comment: I am already using the SpringBootTest + AutoConfigureMockMvc. The MokcMvc was working fine before adding the context-path. So, the problem is not around its configuration